# Does evolution cost increase?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was leveling up a lot of weedles and noticed the candy cost rose from 12 per evolution to 25. Does anyone know how many times you need to evolve a Pokemon before its base cost increases?

Comment: Is it the evolution cost of Weedle that went up, or the fact that Kakuna takes 25 candies to evolve?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you must have mistaken weedle for another pokemon. The evolution cost will always stay the same. The only thing that changes overtime (for that specific pokemon) is the power up cost. Which may rise from 1 to 2 candies.

Comment: Your right thank you, I believe a graphical bug tricked me, I was switching between some rattatas and my weedles and I think the evolution cost counter did not update. But after a restart it seems to have fixed this, Thanks!